# How to set correct MTU for a particular OpenVPN link

Tags: vpn, mtu, sslvpn

How to set the correct MTU on OpenVPN server client connection ?

The highest payload that can be successfully sent from here is 1402 from a Win7 PC.
    ping host -l 1402 -f

Wireshark shows that the total frame size of the above ICMP packet is 1444 bytes.

I am uncertain of which options would I need to add to the OpenVPN configuration, *link-mtu*, *tun-mtu* or *mssfix* and their respective values to get my connection up.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional managed networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they functions rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.